# How to give color to a selected group of text in textAngular?

Tags: angularjs

How can I give color to a specific group of text in textAngular ? I'm using version 1.2.1. I have visited git hub repo but couldn't find anything.

I need a example how to do it .

Comment: Can you explain more about it? what have you tried?

Comment: I can't see a option there to change colors of seleced text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was looking for the font color in textAngular and I found that we need to customize the tools to add this feature.

So I found this link:
***Have a look at the Creating and Editing the tools***
https://github.com/fraywing/textAngular/wiki/Customising-The-Toolbar

Also see this : https://github.com/fraywing/textAngular/issues/11

```
color: {
display: "<span class='barBtn'><button type='button' colorpicker class='btn btn-default' ng-class='displayActiveToolClass(active)' ng-disabled='showHtml()'>
 <i class='fa fa-font'></i></button></span>",
   action: function(color) {
      if (color !== '') {
        return this.$parent.wrapSelection('foreColor', color);
      }
   }
},
```

Hope it will give you some idea.

Comment: i have gone through these articles still i m not clear how to do it

Answer (score 0):

From what I've understood you need to change the color of selected text and this can be achieved using  CSS pseudo selector 
  `::selection`.

Refer to this article from [W3 schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_selection.asp) or this [CSS trick](https://css-tricks.com/overriding-the-default-text-selection-color-with-css/) for more details.

Comment: i am expecting from a text editor ( textangular.js) here to show me a group of words in some user choosen color